# Positivity of $dt$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differential-geometry, energy-conservation, entropy

### Background

I had an idea to write time $dt$ in the first law of thermodynamics. So let us proceed with the $1$'st law in differential form:

$$ dw = T dS - d U $$

where $w$ is the work, $T$ is temperature, $S$ is the entropy and $U$ is the internal energy.

Now, let the work be in terms of pressure and volume:

$$ P dV = T dS - d U $$

Dividing by pressure :

$$ dV = \frac{T}{P} dS - \frac{dU}{P}  $$
Taking the hodge dual:

$$  dt =   \star ( \frac{T}{P} dS - \frac{dU}{P} )$$

The below is an attempt. We continue with:

$$  dt =   \star ( \frac{T}{P} dS - \frac{dU}{P} )$$

Using,

$$dS = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial S}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial S}{\partial z} dz + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} dt$$

And similarly:

$$dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} dz + \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} dt$$

We have:

$$ dt = \sum_{i} ( \frac{T}{P} \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{P} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} ) \star dx_i $$

where $dx_0 = cdt$, $dx_1 = dx$, $dx_2 = dy$ and $dx_3 = dz$

### Question

Can anyone prove or disprove that if $ dS > 0 $ then $dt > 0$? Using:

$$ dt = \sum_{i} ( \frac{T}{P} \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{P} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} ) \star dx_i $$

Comment: Apologies for the massive edit but I wasn't sure if I should answer my own question and then ask a new one or just do a massive edit.

Comment: What does $dt>0$ mean from the viewpoint of differential geometry?

Comment: @NDewolf I'm not sure if this will sate you (i'm not that good at differential geometry). It means when integrating $t_2 > t_1$. Feel free to recommend an edit?

Comment: Do you assume that $\text{d} V=\text{d}x_1 \,\text{d}x_2\,\text{d}x_3$ so that $*\text{d}V=\text{d}t$?

Comment: @Toffomat yes I do

Comment: Yeah, that's not true. $\text{d} V$ is not the volume form on some manifold that you would integrate over to get the volume of your region/system/whatever. It's a one-form in your space of thermodynamic variables -- just as $\text{d} S$ or $\text{d} U$ are one-forms.

Comment: @Toffomat I wouldn't mind if you wrote an answer going in more depth about this? (Or referring me to one?)

Comment: Also what is $\star dV$ then?

Comment: This paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0868) might shed some light on the issue. The problem is that the volume $V$ should not be viewed as some spatial structure, but instead as a thermodynamic variable. The manifold on which you are working is accordingly not the spatial (4D) spacetime and as such there is not an immediate relation between $V$ and $t$.

Comment: @NDewolf +1 I'll go through it for sure. So when I integrate $dV$ from work I won't get the usual volume? I find this quite confusing.

Comment: Integrating $dV$ should still give you the volume (change), however it is not related to the volume form on the ordinary spacetime manifold. It is just (the differential of) some coordinate on the "thermodynamic" phase space.

Comment: @NDewolf feel free to explain here? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531082/intuition-of-dv-in-pdv