# Intuition of $dV$ in $PdV$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, energy-conservation, volume

I seem to have some [misunderstanding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531064/positivity-of-dt) of $PdV$ in the first law of thermodynamics.

$$ P dV = T dS - d U $$

I have a ballon. I apply some work (or change the temperature inside the balloon). Now, there are $2$ ways I have to describe the change in volume.

1. Measure the change in volume in real space.
2. Measure the change in the thermodynamic variables $P,V,N$ and use the ideal gas equation

$$ PV = NRT$$

in phase space. Now, I'm quite confused if $dV$ is a one form or something like $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$?

Comment: The equation you wrote for the first law applies strictly to a system that does not exchange mass with its surroundings, and your balloon receives air (mass) from its surroundings.

Comment: Your equations are for a closed system (a system that does not exchange mass with the surroundings). Your balloon example is an open system since you are blowing air into it (i.e., N is not a constant in the ideal gas equation).

Comment: @ChetMiller Oops! Didn't see your comment before I made mine.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have edited the question. The crux still remains imo.

Comment: $dV$ is just a one-form. The thermodynamic description is largely agnostic to the spatial geometry and just treats volume as an abstract degree of freedom.

Comment: @Christoph so what happens to a gas in curved spacetime?

Comment: This will probably depend on the properties of the spacetime. However this dependence will be built-in into the thermodynamic phase space defined by the variables $E, P, V, T,...$. See the last section of the paper I posted on your other question (https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0868).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter whether you have an ideal gas or whether you exchange heat/mass/energy with your surroundings, the general setup is the following: You have a thermodynamic system that is described by a number of variables such as temperature, internal energy, pressure etc. Some of these  will be the coordinates of your configuration space (they are generally not all independent). One of these variables is the volume $V$ -- this is the complete volume of the system (ballon, cylinder with piston,...), not some infinitesimal volume element to integrate over.

The first law of thermodynamics now gives you a relation between the changes in volume and entropy, $\text{d} V$ and $\text{d}S$, and the change in internal energy. Thus, expression such as $\text{d}V$ or $\text{d}U$ are one-forms, i.e. you can think of them as infinitesimal changes in the variables describing your system.